# Python: Closing an opened URL via contextlib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm using `urllib.request` to periodically check whether I'm connected to the internet so I'm concerned about opening too many instances. I close them using the following piece of code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from contextlib import closing

def internet_on():
    try:
        with closing(urlopen('http://google.com', timeout=1)) as x:
            return True
    except BaseException as err: 
        return False`
```

Is this an effective way of preventing open instances?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `urlopen` always returns an object which is a context manager, so you *should* be able to just do:

```py
def internet_on():
    try:
        with urlopen('http://google.com', timeout=1):
            return True
    except urllib.error.URLError: 
        return False
```

That is, using `contextlib.closing()` adds nothing here.

That said, here are some additional thoughts:

(1) You should not be using `BaseException` - it's very broad and should very rarely be used directly. For example, you will get `False` even if your code breaks and will *never* work because you introduced some breaking change. Find out which more specific exception types are likely to happen because of a TCP connection error or anything that might be reasonably thrown when this fails because of connectivity issues, and only catch that.

(2) Have you been seeing an actual too many open connections problem, or are you just worried about it?

HTTP is (broadly speaking) a stateless protocol, and AFAIK `urlopen` doesn't go out of it's way to keep connections open after a request has been made, which it's unlikely you'll end up with a still-open connection once you are inside your `with` context - by then either the request was done and the connection was already closed or it has failed and urllib will throw before you get there (and probably close it's own TCP connection doing that). So unless you're doing something special, I'm pretty sure you won't see dangling connections with `urlopen` and the context manager isn't needed at all.